# How to get position of certain color range from image?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

[image: xmas tree]

I have this image of a Xmas tree, with different circles on its branches. You can see the circles are in different colors: Green, red, yellow etc.

I have to find the position of the circles using PHP.

Is it possible with the PHP GD library?

If it is possible please suggest me how can I calculate the circles' x and y position.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with the GD library but with imagemagick.

Color changes and their location in images are found through [Edge Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection).

There is a nice wrapup of this for php in this [blog article](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/10/19/image-edge-detection-algorithm-php-version/).

There is no general script i could give you since finding the correct algorithm four your source image is an iterative process.

first you would try to filter the dark green colors of the tree out of the source image, then you could run the edge detection to get the edges of the circles in a greyscale image.

once you are there you need some sort of circle detection. google found this interesting [thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/38544/circle-detection-algorithm)

hope this helps to push you in the right direction.